# Evaluating if statement in brackets and assigning to HTML tag

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

I have a ng-repeat that has an array in an object. ex: `contract.fields[4]`.

```
<tbody data-ng-repeat="(contractIndex,contract) in contracts">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div data-strat-form-control
                 data-field-display-id="1"
                 data-vmformreadonly="true"
                 data-show-tool-tip="showToolTip(contract.fields[3].htmlName)"
                 data-strat-model="contract"
                 data-field="contract.fields[1]">
            </div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div data-strat-form-control
                 data-field-display-id="1"
                 data-vmformreadonly="true"
                 data-show-tool-tip="showToolTip(contract.fields[4].htmlName)"
                 data-strat-model="contract"
                 data-field="contract.fields[3]">
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

I want to ad in aan if statement so that a different contract.fields array location will go under data-field tag.

```
<div data-strat-form-control
     data-field-display-id="1"
     data-vmformreadonly="true"
     data-show-tool-tip="showToolTip(contract.fields[3].htmlName)"
     data-strat-model="contract"
     data-field="{{contract.COMMIT_CONTRACT.length > 1 | 'contract.fields[1]' : 'contract.fields[2]'}}">
 </div>
```

Here is the bracket notation separately:

```
{{contract.COMMIT_CONTRACT.length > 1 | 'contract.fields[1]' : 'contract.fields[2]'}}
```

Something is wrong with this code but it looks like I am doing something wrong. What is it and how do I fix it?

Comment: Not quite sure I understand your question, but if you want to use a ternary operator, then it's `condition ? value if true : value if false`, i.e. you should use `?`, not `|`. Also you most certainly don't want to encode either value in quotes. And beware of precedence with `?:`.

Comment: Like this?: `{{contract.COMMIT_CONTRACT.length > 1 ? 'contract.fields[3]' : 'contract.fields[4]'}}`  I am getting:  Syntax Error: Token 'contract.COMMIT_CONTRACT.length' is unexpected, expecting [:] at column 3 of the expression

Comment: You don't need the quotes, and I would think you don't need the brackets either. `(contract.COMMIT_CONTRACT.length > 1) ? contract.fields[3] : contract.fields[4]` should be enough?

Comment: @jcaron Hey yes, I misread before but without the brackets this is working. Thank you! Put an answer if you would like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your expression seems wrong. First you don't need {{}} inside the data-field attribute. 
Then single apices should be removed.
Then it seems you want to use a ternary operator but that syntax is wrong.
I think your expression should be simply:

```
contract.COMMIT_CONTRACT.length > 1 ? contract.fields[1] : contract.fields[2]
```